# Decrypt Password Created by crypto.pbkdf2 Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I have the following code in javascript, running on NodeJs:

```
encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password || !this.salt) return '';
    var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
}
```

How can I implement the decrypt function? 
It can be in java or in javascript.

Thx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PBKDF2 is a one-way hashing algorithm. It's not possible to decrypt the generated hash. You can read more about this [here](http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/06/08/securing-passwords-hashes-pbkdf2/).

> A one way hash performs a bunch of mathematical operations that
>   transform input into a (mostly) unique output, called a digest.
>   Because these operations are one way, you cannot ‘decrypt’ the output-
>   you can’t turn a digest into the original input.

If you want to use PBKDF2 to store and compare passwords, you might be interested in the [`pbkdf2`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pbkdf2) library. It makes generation and comparison of passwords easy:

```
var pbkdf2 = require('pbkdf2');
var p = 'password';
var s = pbkdf2.generateSaltSync(32);
var pwd = pbkdf2.hashSync(p, s, 1, 20, 'sha256');
var bool = pbkdf2.compareSync(pwd, p, s, 1, 20, 'sha256');
```

Comment: Thx. Compaing passwords is pretty easy without your code. We can just compare strings. As far as I understand it, using my function above on same two strings will return the same hashed password.